# Laravel FormRequest validation rules not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, validation

In my Laravel app, I am creating a dynamic search functionality using Eloquent and I have a customer search form which looks like this:

**customers.search.blade.php** *Contrived Example*

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('customers.search') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name" class="font-weight-bold">First Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <select name="first_name['operator']" class="custom-select">
                    <option value="%">%</option>
                    <option value="=">=</option>
                    <option value="!=">!=</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input id="first_name" name="first_name['query']" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a `SearchCustomerRequest` (FormRequest) class which builds out the validation rules dynamically. I've dumped it, so you can see what the generated rules looks like:

[image]

In my **CustomersController** under `search` method, I did the following to see what the validated request array looks like:

```
class CustomersController extends Controller
{

    // ...

    public function search(SearchCustomerRequest $searchCustomerRequest)
    {
        dd($searchCustomerRequest->validated());
    }

    // ...

}
```

In order to test this, in the search form, I've selected the `firstname['operator']` to `%` and typed the `first_name['query']` to `test` and submitted the form.

I got the following response (*i.e. empty array*):

> []

So, I dumped the whole request object `$searchCustomerRequest` to see what was in the parameter bag and this is what I see:

[image]

As you can see, my request is valid and my rules also *looks* correct, yet the validation doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ParameterBag`, the `first_name` properties `operator` and `query` are enclosed in single quotes. In your HTML, the name attribute should exclude the single quotes. Ex: `name="first_name[query]"`

Comment: Thanks @pablo. Nice catch.